# Apply number format to sheets at the same time

Tags: google-sheets

I want to apply number format to **A1**, **A2**, and **A3** cell range from **Sheet1** until **Sheet50** at the same time.

I am doing it sheet by sheet but is really slow.

I use Google Sheets but I can use Microsoft Excel or LibreOffice if can't be done with Google Sheets.

Answer (score 1):

In Excel it is fairly straight forward to select a range which is spans multiple worksheets. In Excel terminology this is called a *3-D reference*. Selecting a 3-D reference is fairly straightforward.

1. Select the first worksheet in the desired range of worksheets and hold down the shift key.
2. Select the final worksheet in the desired range. The worksheet selection tabs between the first and the last will all now be highlighted, with the first worksheet highlighted as the active worksheet.
3. Whilst multiple worksheets are highlighted, operations on the active worksheet such as modifying cell values or changing the format of a range of cells, will be replicated across all selected worksheets.
4. Once the replicated operations are complete unselect the range of worksheets by either selecting an unhighlighted worksheet or selecting a highlighted worksheet, right-clicking and choosing "Ungroup Sheets" from the pop-up menu.

3-D references can also be used in formulae, see [this Microsoft article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-3-d-reference-to-the-same-cell-range-on-multiple-worksheets-40ca91ff-9dcb-4ad1-99d2-787d0bc888b6) for more details.

I have no idea whether this method also applies to Google sheets, but it will be easy for you to test on a dummy worksheet.